# spring initializr 2.3.x removed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-initializr

Spring Boot 2.3.12.RELEASE was released on 10th Jun 2021 and in July it's been removed from "spring initializr" page (https://start.spring.io/).

- https://spring.io/blog/2021/06/10/spring-boot-2-3-12-release-available-now

My questions:

1. Is 2.3.x deprecated already?
2. If I want to generate a new Spring Boot project for version 2.3.12, how can I do it? It no longer can be done from "spring initializr" page.

Comment: Change version from `pom.xml`.

Comment: spring initializr also helps us choose other starter dependencies eg. spring cloud project. If we do it manually then choosing the right version for it may not be straight forward. Does it mean, there's not easy way to generate 2.3.x spring boot projects which may include spring cloud as well?

Comment: you can find the descriptive answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538583/did-spring-initializr-stop-support-for-spring-boot-2-x/77698163#77698163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is 2.3.x deprecated already?

Yes. Spring Boot 2.3.x was removed from https://start.spring.io as 2.3.x [reached the end of its open source support period on 15 May 2021](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions#released-versions).

> If I want to generate a new Spring Boot project for version 2.3.12, how can I do it?

Ideally, you shouldn't. Any existing projects that are using Spring Boot 2.3.x should be updated to 2.4.x or 2.5.x as soon as possible and new projects should use 2.4.x or 2.5.x from the outset.

If you have to start a new project using an unsupported version of Spring Boot, you could generate the project and then modify the version in the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file to downgrade the version. This may get harder to do the longer the version has been out of support.

If you are using Spring Cloud, you can use start.spring.io's [info endpoint](https://start.spring.io/actuator/info) to help with version mappings:

```
…
"spring-cloud": {
    "2020.0.0": "Spring Boot >=2.4.0.M4 and <=2.4.0",
    "2020.0.0-M3": "Spring Boot >=2.4.0.M1 and <=2.4.0.M1",
    "2020.0.0-M4": "Spring Boot >=2.4.0.M2 and <=2.4.0-M3",
    "2020.0.3": "Spring Boot >=2.4.1 and <2.5.4-SNAPSHOT",
    "2020.0.4-SNAPSHOT": "Spring Boot >=2.5.4-SNAPSHOT",
    "Hoxton.SR12": "Spring Boot >=2.2.0.RELEASE and <2.4.0.M1"
},
…
```

The above indicates that Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR12 should be used with Spring Boot 2.3.x (and 2.2.x).

Note that [Spring Cloud Hoxton is also out of its OSS support period](https://spring.io/blog/2021/07/07/spring-cloud-hoxton-sr12-has-been-released) so you really should be looking to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4.x or 2.5.x and Spring Cloud 2020.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer-1:** Check @andy-wilkinson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68590105/1548586).
**Answer-2:** You can use Spring-CLI

**Steps:**

1. Install [Spring-CLI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli.html#cli.installation)
2. Run following command

> spring init --boot-version=2.3.12.RELEASE  --dependencies=web,data-jpa
> old-boot-project

For more on Spring-CLI. Please check official documents [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli.html#cli.using-the-cli.initialize-new-project)

Comment: This answer doesn't help, as spring-cli is using https://start.spring.io. So same restrictions apply. Example. Execute command using spring boot cli version 2.7.10:
spring init --type=maven-project --bootVersion=2.7.10
And you get result:
Using service at https://start.spring.io
Initializr service call failed using 'https://start.spring.io' - service returned Bad Request: 'Invalid Spring Boot version '2.7.10', Spring Boot compatibility range is >=3.1.0'